# What is Noether's Second Theorem?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, gauge-theory, noethers-theorem, gauge-invariance

I have been unable to find a short statement of [Noether's second theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_second_theorem). It would be helpful to have the following:

1. A short mathematical statement of the theorem. Does it imply a conservation law and strong identities?
2. A short derivation of it, so that it is clear what assumptions are made. (Here I have in mind that an assumption of boundary conditions is being made.)

This question is motivated by the recent developments of asymptotic symmetries in gauge theories.

Comment: I have been led to Noether's second theorem some months ago because of the same reason, in particular the equivalence between asymptotic symmetries and soft theorems. I suggest having a look at this paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.07038) since it is a quick introduction to the subject. Noether's two theorems are explained in section 2. If you have more time available this paper by Barnich (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0111246) may also be helpful.

Comment: Slide 48 of https://www-users.math.umn.edu/~olver/t_/noetherth.pdf may help.